# Select a radio option and then click the same option again to submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a question relating to using radio to submit a form, but only if an option is selected and thenthe same option is clicked again. The purpose is to allow the user to select from a range of radio options, and then confirm their choice by clicking their preferred option again, triggering the form to submit. I have tried many ways to achieve this, but I'm not even close. Any guidance hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hi tomo. Could you please let us know what you have tried? Also, are you sure the idea to get a user to click a radio button twice is the best from a user experience perspective?

Comment: Hi Romi, thanks for this. I've tried firstly getting the value of the selected radio, and I have played around with submit .onchange trigger and .onlick trigger firing an alert with the selected radio value. Where I am stuck is trying to determine if an option is already selected, and if so, submit the form when clicked again. The reason for this approach is a quite specific application so we're confident it's the right UI approach - if there was an better and easier approach I'd take it for sure! If the same effect can be achieved with buttons rather than radio then that would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your problem, On select radio saving that reference in hidden field.
May be this could help you

```js
document.getElementById('hidden').value="";
     function check(val){
        if( document.getElementById('hidden').value === val){
            alert('submit');
        }else{
                document.getElementById('hidden').value = val
          alert(val);
        }

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h4>First Select and click the selected option to sumit</h4>

  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option1"  onclick="check(this.value)"> Option1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option2"  onclick="check(this.value)"> Option2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option3" onclick="check(this.value)"> Option3
<br/>
Choosed Option<input type="text" value="" id="hidden">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

make your button

```
 input type="submit"
```

to

```
input type="button"
```

or

in click event function write this code:

```
$("#your-form-id").submit(function(ev){ev.preventDefault();});
```